# Deleting a row which is substring of the subsequent row

Tags: regex, openoffice-calc

In Libre office calc , I have a criteria where in I need to delete a row in case it is substring of the previous row .
i.e
If the input is

> ABC
>
> ABCDE
>
> XYZ
>
> XYZRE

and I apply the regex , the output must be

> ABCDE
>
> XYZRE

Comment: Try replacing `^(.+)[\r\n]+\1` with `$1`.

Comment: Sorry @WiktorStribiżew . I am not able to follow the answer

Comment: The way I understand regex in LO they are applied per cell, not per spreadsheet. An easy work around would be to export your spreadsheet from calc to a CSV format and use Wiktor Stribiżews regex on that inside text editor that handles regex serch and replace.

Comment: Thank you both  . I am doing it as CSV . But the problem is that its selecting both the entries and replacing them . I just want to retain the second occurrence , while deleting the first one.

Comment: So , I slightly modified @WiktorStribiżew's answer replacing the $1 with /1

Comment: You need to capture a line, then a linbreak and then use a backreference to the captured group value to make sure the next line starts with the whole line before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture a line, then a linebreak and then use a backreference to the captured group value to make sure the next line starts with the whole line before it.

Use

```
 ^(.+)[\r\n]+\1
```

Replace with

```
 $1
```

Some editors require `\1` instead of `$1`.